# How to download file from internet via R

Tags: r, download

I have an url, and I want to download the file via `R`, I notice that `download.file` would be helpful, but my problem seems different:

```
url <- "http://journal.gucas.ac.cn/CN/article/downloadArticleFile.do?attachType=PDF&id=11771"
destfile <- "myfile.pdf"
download.file(url, destfile)
```

It doesn't work! I notice that if my `url` is in the form of `xxx.pdf`, then the code above is no problem, otherwise the file that is downloaded is corrupt.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please define `it doesn't work`. I can download the file using `download.file` and open it using a PDF reader, so I cannot reproduce your problem. My first guess would be you are behind a web proxy...

Comment: I run the code, and can get the file "myfile.pdf", but when I click on the file "myfile.pdf", I can not open it, so I think maybe I didn't download it in the right way.

Comment: The download works fine for me too, and I can open the PDF. The PDF is in Chinese, though, maybe you are simply missing Chinese fonts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Setting the mode might be required to treat the file as binary data while saving it. If I leave that argument out, I get a blank file, but this way works for me:

```
url <- "http://journal.gucas.ac.cn/CN/article/downloadArticleFile.do?
attachType=PDF&id=11771"
destfile <- "myfile.pdf"
download.file(url, destfile, mode="wb")
```

Comment: Can you specify your operating system and version of R? The `mode` parameter is only used when the `internal` method is used. The default method is `auto` so I suspect that it may depend on the OS. I have no problem in downloading the file using R 3.0.2 under FC18 64bit.

Comment: platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          0.2                         
year           2013                        
month          09                          
day            25                          
svn rev        63987

Comment: I think probably it's to do with how the ISP transmits http binary streams, which would explain why it works for some people without enforcement of mode and not for others.

Comment: I need to add method='curl' also to not get a corrupt pdf. RStudio Version 0.98.1103 R 3.1.2 on windows.

Comment: Im using all these methods and its still not creating a workable file for me. It fails on trying to open it up.

Answer (score -2):

I am trying to download an nc file with R. It downloads well but I get this error when trying to open it:

> Error in R_nc4_open: NetCDF: Unknown file format Error in
> nc_open("SM_D2010323_Map_SATSSS_data_1day.nc") :    Error in nc_open
> trying to open file SM_D2010323_Map_SATSSS_data_1day.nc
> (return_on_error= FALSE )

```
url <- "https://www.star.nesdis.noaa.gov/data/socd1/coastwatch/products/miras/nc/SM_D2010323_Map_SATSSS_data_1day.nc"
destfile <- "***/SM_D2010323_Map_SATSSS_data_1day.nc"
download.file(url, destfile)
nc_data <- nc_open('SM_D2010323_Map_SATSSS_data_1day.nc')
```

But when I use the same URL on my web browser, I can open the file without any problems with R.

Comment: Sorry this has nothing to do with the subject, ask your own question :)