# Download file from internet via R despite the popup

Tags: r, download, popup

Downloading a file from the internet using R is easy and [has been addressed previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20028061/how-to-download-file-from-internet-via-r).

My question regards how to get past a popup message that seems to prevent my download from executing.  Specifically,

```
download.file(url = "https://www.chicagofed.org/applications/bhc_data/bhcdata_index.cfm?DYR=2012&DQIR=4", destfile = "data/test.zip")
```

gives me a little file of garbage instead of the desired 18 megabyte file that you would get if you went to [the website](https://www.chicagofed.org/applications/bhc_data/bhcdata_index.cfm) and entered the year `2012` and the quarter `4` manually.  I suspect that the issue is that, as can be seen when you do it manually, a popup window interrupts the download process, asking whether to save the file or open it.  Is there any way to get past the popup automatically (i.e., via `download.file`)?

Answer (score 6):

This can be done with Selenium see https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium.

```
require(wdman)
require(RSelenium)


selPort <- 4444L
fprof <- makeFirefoxProfile(list(browser.download.dir = "C:\\temp"
                                 ,  browser.download.folderList = 2L
                                 , browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting = FALSE
                                 , browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk = "application/zip"))
selServ <- selenium(port = selPort)
remDr <- remoteDriver(extraCapabilities = fprof, port = selPort)
remDr$open(silent = TRUE)
remDr$navigate("https://www.chicagofed.org/applications/bhc_data/bhcdata_index.cfm")
# click year 2012
webElem <- remDr$findElement("name", "SelectedYear")
webElems <- webElem$findChildElements("css selector", "option")
webElems[[which(sapply(webElems, function(x){x$getElementText()}) == "2012" )]]$clickElement()

# click required quarter

webElem <- remDr$findElement("name", "SelectedQuarter")
Sys.sleep(1)
webElems <- webElem$findChildElements("css selector", "option")
webElems[[which(sapply(webElems, function(x){x$getElementText()}) == "4th Quarter" )]]$clickElement()

# click button

webElem <- remDr$findElement("id", "downloadDataFile")
webElem$clickElement()
```