# Downloading SRTM data with raster package?

Tags: r, zip, raster, srtm

I'm trying to get SRTM data with "`raster`" package in R, but as soon as I'm choosing `SRTM` in getData command, I would get the following error:

```
library(raster)

srtm <- getData('SRTM', lon=16, lat=48)
trying URL 'ftp://xftp.jrc.it/pub/srtmV4/tiff/srtm_40_03.zip'
trying URL 'http://hypersphere.telascience.org/elevation/cgiar_srtm_v4/tiff/zip/srtm_40_03.ZIP'
downloaded 572 bytes

Error in .SRTM(..., download = download, path = path) : file not found
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In utils::download.file(url = aurl, destfile = fn, method = "auto",  :
  URL 'ftp://xftp.jrc.it/pub/srtmV4/tiff/srtm_40_03.zip': status was 'Couldn't resolve host name'
2: In utils::unzip(zipfilename, exdir = dirname(zipfilename)) :
  error 1 in extracting from zip file
```

Any Idea what is this error for ?

Comment: I get the same error. Looks like that telascience.org link is broken. It wont open with a browser either.

Comment: works for me. but my raster version also tries to access a third link: http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/SRT-ZIP/SRTM_V41/SRTM_Data_GeoTiff/srtm_40_03.ZIP
and this finally works

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem, it seems to be a bug. The `getData` function in `raster` package checks for availability of the raster file in three different url's.

```
1. ftp://xftp.jrc.it/pub/srtmV4/tiff/FILENAME
2. http://hypersphere.telascience.org/elevation/cgiar_srtm_v4/tiff/zip/FILENAME
3. http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/SRT-ZIP/SRTM_V41/SRTM_Data_GeoTiff/FILENAME
```

The first two of them (as of today) are not working or cannot be accessible. However for some reason a small bit data is getting transferred across the server, so the package assumes it to be a available file only to reach an error by `utils`. The third url however is most trusted one among the three.

I did some digging and came up with the following function after slightly modifying the `raster` package itself so that it uses the third url. You can input `Longitude` and `Latitude` values here. Note that this is only useful if you want to download the files based on Latitude & Longitude.

```
SRTM<-function(lon, lat) {
  stopifnot(lon >= -180 & lon <= 180)
  stopifnot(lat >= -60 & lat <= 60)
  rs <- raster(nrows=24, ncols=72, xmn=-180, xmx=180, ymn=-60, ymx=60 )
  rowTile <- rowFromY(rs, lat)
  colTile <- colFromX(rs, lon)
  if (rowTile < 10) { rowTile <- paste('0', rowTile, sep='') }
  if (colTile < 10) { colTile <- paste('0', colTile, sep='') }

  f <- paste('srtm_', colTile, '_', rowTile, sep="")
  theurl <- paste("http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/wp-content/uploads/files/srtm_5x5/TIFF/", f, ".ZIP", sep="")
  utils::download.file(url=theurl, destfile='srtm_40_0.zip', method="auto", quiet = FALSE, mode = "wb", cacheOK = TRUE)
}
```

Example:

```
SRTM(lon=16, lat=48)
```

This will result in a file named `srtm_40_03.zip` in your folder which would normally contain a `tif`, a `hdr` and a `tfw` file of the same name. Use them for further process as usual.

**EDIT DATE 22-JAN-19:**
The srtm link as changed (as well), the above code has been adapted to reflect this.

Comment: This still does not work for me :`SRTM(lon=16, lat=48)
trying URL 'http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/SRT-ZIP/SRTM_V41/SRTM_Data_GeoTiff/srtm_40_03.ZIP'
Error in utils::download.file(url = theurl, destfile = "srtm_40_03.zip",  : 
  cannot open URL 'http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/SRT-ZIP/SRTM_V41/SRTM_Data_GeoTiff/srtm_40_03.ZIP'
In addition: Warning message:
In utils::download.file(url = theurl, destfile = "srtm_40_03.zip",  :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The operation timed out'`

Comment: Can you visit the link with the browser?

Comment: Yes, It is downloading when I copy the link to the browser

Comment: Then the code should work, I have re-checked. See if all required packages are installed, and try again. If it doesn't work then probably you have issues with R-Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error while trying to downldoad SRTM data using `raster::getData()`. As mentioned by [samAct](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5869242/samact), the problem is related to the URL's that are not accessible anymore.

My solution was to edit the getData function so that it tries first the `http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/SRT-ZIP/SRTM_V41/SRTM_Data_GeoTiff/FILENAME` URL.

To use my edited version of the raster package simply use `devtools::install_github("pokyah/raster"). This will overwrite your current version and make the getData work with the valid URL.

```
devtools::install_github("pokyah/raster")
library(raster)
```

Then, you can use this function to download the SRTM data for your region of interest :

```
# @param country_code.chr a character specifying the ISO contrycode. Ex : BE for belgium
# @param NAME_1.chr a character specifying the NAME_1 value for lower than country level information
# @param aggregation_factor.num a numeric specifying the aggregation factor to get the desired spatial resolution
# @param EPSG.chr a character specifying the EPSG code of the desired Coordiante Reference System (CRS)
# @param path.chr a character specifying the path where to dowload the SRTM data

build_highRes_terrain_rasters.fun <- function(country_code.chr, NAME_1.chr=NULL, aggregation_factor.num=NULL, EPSG.chr=NULL, path.chr) {
  # Path to downloaded SRTM Tiles refs
  srtm.tiles.ref <- raster::shapefile("<PATH_TO_DOWNLOADED_TILES_REFS")

  # Get country geometry first
  extent.sp <- raster::getData('GADM', country=country_code.chr, level=1)

  if(!is.null(NAME_1.chr)){
    extent.sp <- subset(extent.sp, NAME_1 == NAME_1.chr)
  }

  # Intersect extent geometry and tile grid
  intersects <- rgeos::gIntersects(extent.sp, srtm.tiles.ref, byid=T)
  tiles      <- srtm.tiles.ref[intersects[,1],]

  # Download tiles using getData
  # inspired from https://www.gis-blog.com/download-srtm-for-an-entire-country/
  srtm_list  <- list()
  for(i in 1:length(tiles)) {
    lon <- extent(tiles[i,])[1]  + (extent(tiles[i,])[2] - extent(tiles[i,])[1]) / 2
    lat <- extent(tiles[i,])[3]  + (extent(tiles[i,])[4] - extent(tiles[i,])[3]) / 2

    tile <- getData('SRTM', #data are downloaded from http://www.cgiar-csi.org/. See getData do of pokyah/raster repo on github
                    lon=lon,
                    lat=lat,
                    download = FALSE,
                    path = path.chr)

    srtm_list[[i]] <- tile
  }

  # Mosaic tiles
  srtm_list$fun <- mean
  srtm_mosaic.ras <- do.call(raster::mosaic, srtm_list)

  # Crop tiles to extent borders
  extent.elevation.ras <- raster::crop(srtm_mosaic.ras, extent.sp)
  extent.elevation.ras <- raster::mask(extent.elevation.ras, extent.sp)

  # transform to desired CRS
  if(!is.null(EPSG.chr)){
    raster::projectRaster(extent.elevation.ras, crs = toString((dplyr::filter(rgdal::make_EPSG(), code==EPSG.chr))$prj4))
  }

  # aggregate to lower resolution
  # inspired from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32278825/how-to-change-the-resolution-of-a-raster-layer-in-r
  if(!is.null(aggregation_factor.num)){
    extent.elevation.ras <- raster::aggregate(extent.elevation.ras, fact=aggregation_factor.num)
  }

  # compute the slope from the elevation
  # inspired from https://rpubs.com/etiennebr/visualraster
  extent.slope.ras <- raster::terrain(extent.elevation.ras, opt="slope", unit="degrees")
  extent.aspect.ras <- raster::terrain(extent.elevation.ras, opt="aspect", unit="degrees")
  extent.roughness.ras <- raster::terrain(extent.elevation.ras, opt="roughness")

  # compute the aspect from the elevation
  extent.terrain.ras = raster::stack(
    extent.elevation.ras,
    extent.slope.ras,
    extent.aspect.ras,
    extent.roughness.ras)
}
```

hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

today, 21-01-2019, the link was still broken, even the one corrected by pokyah. New working version at:

```
devtools::install_github("fedefyco/raster")
library(raster)
```

Comment: Yes true, the above code is now fixed for the new link as well.

Answer (score 0):

I got all the same errors and I found a solution using `httr` package to download it ([source here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71077601/2444948)).

I tried **BUT THIS DID NOT WORK**:

```r
url <- "https://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/wp-content/uploads/files/srtm_5x5/TIFF/srtm_37_04.zip"

library(RCurl)
url2 <- getURL(url)

download.file(url, "test", mode = "auto", method = "curl")
download.file(url, "test", mode = "wb", method = "curl")
download.file(url, "test")
# ... and so on 

library(data.table)
fread(url)
```

This worked:

```r
library(httr)
httr::set_config(httr::config(ssl_verifypeer=0L))
GET(url, httr::write_disk(path = basename(url), overwrite = TRUE))
```

I needed to change the raster `.download` function for this. I could make definitive changes with `reassignInPackage` from `R.utils` (I think it is definitive) (`reassignInPackage(name=".download", pkgName="raster", value="my.fn")`) but I prefer a temporary change.

Place this in your code and it will fix the `getData` function:

```r
y.fn <- function(aurl, filename){
  cat("You wanna download: ", aurl, "\n")
  cat("You wanna save it there : ", filename, "\n\n")
  httr::set_config(httr::config(ssl_verifypeer=0L))
  httr::GET(aurl, httr::write_disk(path = filename, overwrite = TRUE))
}
tmpfun <- get(".download", envir = asNamespace("raster"))
environment(my.fn) <- environment(tmpfun)
attributes(my.fn) <- attributes(tmpfun)  # don't know if this is really needed
assignInNamespace(".download", my.fn, ns="raster")
```

and try again