# Error in R package Raster

Tags: r, r-raster, srtm

I am working with R package `raster` for sometime now. Recently I updated my system to Windows 10 where I used the a backup R package file to install-back all my packages.

Now while using `raster` packages especially when I use:

`getData('SRTM', lon= Longitiude, lat =Latitude)`

I get the follwoing error:

```
trying URL 'ftp://xftp.jrc.it/pub/srtmV4/tiff/srtm_50_08.zip'
downloaded 263 bytes
Error in .SRTM(..., download = download, path = path) : file not found
In addition: Warning message:
In utils::unzip(zipfilename, exdir = dirname(zipfilename)) :
  error 1 in extracting from zip file
```

I read through a few post that says that the url is no longer accessible, this true and can be checked just by visiting the link.

However `getData` function should move-on to the next link which is accessable automatically  but it is not doing that. Is there a way I can tell it to look for the other links.

Comment: Could be that the server(s) are temporarily down. If the problem persists, you could/should contact the maintainer ... who happens to be on SO regularly, so maybe he'll see this and cares to comment.

Comment: Yes I am certain that the servers are down, I have listed an answer to this similar problem here-  https://stackoverflow.com/a/50840963/5869242