# Certificate required for download.file() R

Tags: r, git, github, https, download

I am trying to download a data package from KNB and keep getting an "cannot open URL" and "InternetOpenUrl failed: 'A certificate is required to complete client authentication'". I have checked my github credentials and everything seems to be in order, but I just updated git and setup a PAT. Code below, but note that you will have to set your own directory.

This worked literally two weeks ago. Not sure what changed.

```
download.file("https://knb.ecoinformatics.org/knb/d1/mn/v2/packages/application%2Fbagit-097/resource_map_urn%3Auuid%3A14644b19-6e53-4063-aad9-fc823a45ac50", destfile = #your dir#, method = "wininet")
```

Comment: Update: Switching method to "libcurl' seems to work. However, now there is an issue unzipping the file, that did not exist before.

Comment: set the write mode to binary with `mode = "wb"` to avoid the unzipping issue

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74493075/2444948

Answer (score 0):

The suggested adding 'mode = "wb"' to download.file() works. I have been able to download, unzip and access the various data types in the downloaded folder.

Thank you!

```
download.file("https://knb.ecoinformatics.org/knb/d1/mn/v2/packages/application%2Fbagit-097/resource_map_urn%3Auuid%3A14644b19-6e53-4063-aad9-fc823a45ac50", destfile = #your dir#, method = "libcurl", mode = "wb")

unzip(zipfile = "./data.zip", exdir = "./data")
```