# How do I download file from the internet on R?

Tags: r

Hi I am trying to download an excel report from my company's website using the download.file function. But I am getting an error  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'A certificate is required to complete client authentication'. How do I fix this ?

Comment: please share code or an example of code so others can help. it possibly sounds like a security issue but do not know for certain.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/65586923/3358272 . This suggests both `method="libcurl"` and (perhaps) `mode="wb"`.

Comment: My guess is that this is more related to your internet settings.

Comment: It may be simpler to use your web browser to access the link and download the file. Then move it to the directory where you keep your R work and access it using R functions to convert Excel files.